# Excel, count characters except a string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm using Excel 2013. Basically I'm trying to count the number of characters within a cell, but if the cell contains a specified string to ignore that string but count the rest.

[image: Excel_screenshot]

Looking at the above image, i can use the len formula to count the number of characters in cell A1. Pretty simple. But i'm finding it difficult to work out how to count ONLY the section highlighted in red in cell A2.

**if** (doesn't happen always) a user places the parameter {location:} within the cell i only want to count the characters *between* the colon and the closing curly brace.

I've tried using Len with substitute but I don't think i'm doing it correctly. is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the formula you need:

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND(":",A1,1)),LEN(A1),LEN(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1,1)-1))))
```

The formula checks if there is a **":"** character on the cell content.

If it doesn't exist then only calculates the length of the string.

If it exists then calculate the length of the string extracted from the position next  to ":" and one position before the end.